# Oracle PL SQL, Simplifying my procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I have a following procedure.

```
PROCEDURE PROC_SELECT_ORDERTBL(
   my_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
   p_ORDER_ID IN VARCHAR2
   ...
)
BEGIN
    IF p_ORDER_ID IS NULL THEN
       OPEN my_cursor FOR
       [VERY LONG SELECT STATEMENT1]
    ELSE
       OPEN my_cursor FOR
       [VERY LONG SELECT STATEMENT2]
    END IF;

END PROC_SELECT_ORDERTBL
```

select statement 1 and 2 are almost same.

statement2 = statement1 + where clase(checking p_ORDER_ID)

I want to simplifying my procedure like next.

```
PROCEDURE PROC_SELECT_ORDERTBL(
   my_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
   p_ORDER_ID IN VARCHAR2
   ...
)
BEGIN

    WITH viewData AS
    [VERY LONG SELECT STATEMENT1]

    IF p_ORDER_ID IS NULL THEN
       OPEN my_cursor FOR
       viewData
    ELSE
       OPEN my_cursor FOR
       viewData + where clause
    END IF;

END PROC_SELECT_ORDERTBL
```

But this doesn't compile.

----------------------This in my whole procedure code-------------------

```
  -- ORDERTBL 종이식권 주문단위로 조회
  PROCEDURE PROC_SELECT_ORDERTBL (
    my_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,  -- CURSOR
    p_AREA_ID IN VARCHAR2,    -- AREA_ID
    p_EQP_ID IN VARCHAR2,     -- EQP_ID
    p_ORDER_ID IN VARCHAR2,   -- ORDER_ID
    p_date_from IN VARCHAR2,  -- yymmdd 조회시작일
    p_date_to IN VARCHAR2,    -- yymmdd 조회종료일
    p_errorcode OUT NUMBER    -- error code
  ) AS
  BEGIN
    p_errorcode := 0;

    IF p_ORDER_ID IS NULL THEN
      OPEN my_cursor FOR
        SELECT ORD.ORDER_DATE AS 판매일자, ORD.ORDER_TIME AS 판매시간, ORD_ID.ORDER_ID AS 주문번호, TOTAL_SALES AS 판매금액
        FROM
        (
          --판매일자, 판매시간, 판매금액
          SELECT ORDER_DATE, ORDER_TIME, SUM(ORDER_FEE) AS TOTAL_SALES
          FROM 
          (
            SELECT DISTINCT ORDER_DATE, ORDER_TIME, ORDER_FEE FROM ORDERTBL 
            WHERE AREA_ID = p_AREA_ID AND EQP_ID = p_EQP_ID AND
            ORDER_DATE >= p_date_from AND ORDER_DATE <= p_date_to
          )
          GROUP BY ORDER_DATE, ORDER_TIME
        ) ORD
        JOIN 
        (
          --판매일자, 판매시간, 주문번호
          SELECT ORDER_DATE, ORDER_TIME, MIN(ORDER_ID) AS ORDER_ID
          FROM ORDERTBL
          WHERE AREA_ID = p_AREA_ID AND EQP_ID = p_EQP_ID AND
          ORDER_DATE >= p_date_from AND ORDER_DATE <= p_date_to
          GROUP BY ORDER_DATE, ORDER_TIME
        ) ORD_ID
        ON ORD.ORDER_DATE = ORD_ID.ORDER_DATE AND ORD.ORDER_TIME = ORD_ID.ORDER_TIME
        ORDER BY ORD.ORDER_DATE, ORD.ORDER_TIME;
    ELSE
    OPEN my_cursor FOR
      SELECT ORD.ORDER_DATE AS 판매일자, ORD.ORDER_TIME AS 판매시간, ORD_ID.ORDER_ID AS 주문번호, TOTAL_SALES AS 판매금액
      FROM
      (
        --판매일자, 판매시간, 판매금액
        SELECT ORDER_DATE, ORDER_TIME, SUM(ORDER_FEE) AS TOTAL_SALES
        FROM 
        (
          SELECT DISTINCT ORDER_DATE, ORDER_TIME, ORDER_FEE FROM ORDERTBL 
          WHERE AREA_ID = p_AREA_ID AND EQP_ID = p_EQP_ID AND
          ORDER_DATE >= p_date_from AND ORDER_DATE <= p_date_to
        )
        GROUP BY ORDER_DATE, ORDER_TIME
      ) ORD
      JOIN 
      (
        --판매일자, 판매시간, 주문번호
        SELECT ORDER_DATE, ORDER_TIME, MIN(ORDER_ID) AS ORDER_ID
        FROM ORDERTBL
        WHERE AREA_ID = p_AREA_ID AND EQP_ID = p_EQP_ID AND
        ORDER_DATE >= p_date_from AND ORDER_DATE <= p_date_to
        GROUP BY ORDER_DATE, ORDER_TIME
      ) ORD_ID
      ON ORD.ORDER_DATE = ORD_ID.ORDER_DATE AND ORD.ORDER_TIME = ORD_ID.ORDER_TIME
      WHERE ORD_ID.ORDER_ID = p_ORDER_ID;
    END IF;

  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      p_errorcode := SQLCODE;
  END PROC_SELECT_ORDERTBL;
```

Comment: why can't the where clause be conditional on the parameter value(s)? so you get the effect of one sql statement but branching in the where clause. I'd have to see more of the query to give more detail

Comment: I didn't know where clause can be conditinal. Thanks for your comment. I'll find how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CASE` construct in the where clause. The logic would be similar to your IF-ELSE condition. But, it is not a good coding practice.

I would go with `NVL` and `DECODE`.

***Update : The DECODE and NVL parameter values depends on the column data type.***

If `P_ORDER_ID` is `NUMBER` then use :

`WHERE 
DECODE(p_order_id, NULL, 0, ORD_ID.ORDER_ID) = NVL(p_ORDER_ID, 0)`

else if `P_ORDER_ID` is `VARCHAR2` then use :

`WHERE 
DECODE(p_order_id, NULL, '0', ORD_ID.ORDER_ID) = NVL(p_ORDER_ID, '0')`

Comment: I changed your answer little bit. I got ORA-01722 invalid number error. So I changed default value to string type. WHERE DECODE(p_order_id, NULL, '0', ORD_ID.ORDER_ID) = NVL(p_ORDER_ID, '0')

Comment: Ok. I thought `ORDER_ID` is a `NUMBER` data type. Let me edit tmy answer to improvise about data types.